# Error en consulta Linq

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, mvc, entity-framework, linq

Tengo un `DropDownList` con el cual quiero traer de la base de datos los registros de acuerdo al `item` seleccionado, al hacer click en el botón buscar me aparece el siguiente error:

> The entity or complex type 'DB_ALMACENModel.Producto' cannot be
>   constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Este es mi código:

```
public JsonResult BuscarProducto(int tipo)
    {
        IEnumerable<Producto> productos = (from p in db.Producto
                                   join t in db.Tipo on p.TipoID1 equals t.TipoID
                                   join m in db.Marca on p.MarcaID1 equals m.MarcaID
                                   join o in db.Modelo on p.ModeloID1 equals o.ModeloID
                                   join f in db.Fabricante on p.FabricanteID1 equals f.FabricanteID
                                   where a.TipoID1 == tipo
                                   select new Producto()
                                   {
                                       ProductoID = ProductoID,
                                       TipoID1 = p.TipoID1,
                                       MarcaID1 = p.MarcaID1,
                                       ModeloID1 = p.ModeloID1,
                                       FabricanteID1 = p.FabricanteID1
                                   }).ToList();

        var data = productos.Select(p => new
        {
            Tipo = p.TipoID1
        });

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: El problema se debe a esta línea: `select new Arma()`, debería ser `select new Arma`, ya que la instancia del objeto se realiza en automático. Si estás trabajando con Interfaces lo ideal sería que pusieras la definición para saber cómo definir la estructura completa de la consulta

Comment: Efectivamente, no puedes proyectar en una entidad mapeada. Lo que puedes hacer es crear un tipo anónimo. En tu caso, intenta simplemente borrar `Producto()`: `...select new {ProductoID=ProductoId, TipoId1=p.TipoId1..` y posteriormente, si necesitas realmente que sea de tipo `Producto` le puedes añadir `. Select(x=> new Producto {ProductoID= ProductoId...`